# ASCII encode error while writing columns in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
rows = zip(recallid, recalldate, recallnums, name, model, ptype, categoryid, numberofunits)
with open('WIP.csv'.encode('utf-8'), 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)    
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)       #line 46
```

This program gives me an error as - "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position     8: ordinal not in range(128)"

error occurs at line 46.

I am unable to identify error. Please someone help me identify and rectify it.
Original list contains only alphabets, numbers and symbols.

Comment: In python 3.x `encoding` is an argument that you can pass to `open` function. you are encoding the file name.

Comment: I understood your point that I was encoding my filename. So removed it. But where do i put encode then? Also to mention I am on python 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode the data, not the filename:

```
with open('WIP.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
```

If some of your data are not strings:

```
 writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(s, basestring) else s for s in row])
```